# Configure generates additional directories on x86_64 with clang

Tags: makefile, clang, configure, automake

I'm trying to build [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) from source on Mac OS X Yosemite (using clang) with the following commands:

`./auto_gen.sh
./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/own/directory
make
make install`

After that I found that the linker reported library-not-found error with `clang test.c -o test -ljit` command. I checked the directory where the library was installed, and noticed that it was installed to `/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libjit*` instead of `/usr/local/lib/libjit*`, which leaded to the linking error.

I also built the library on my Archlinux box and everything was fine. Comparing the two makefiles generated on different OSes, I saw that the `libdir` variables differed.

I googled and went to pages talking about multiarch on Debian, but I'm not sure if this problem has anything to do with that mechanism.

So how can I change the installation directory to `/usr/local/lib` like other libraries? Or, if that is just the right way, how can I make the linker work correctly?

Comment: In cases like this you have to dig under the hood -- look at the libjit `configure.ac` script and see if it is doing something weird.  There's nothing built-in like this AFAIK.  This hackery happens more often than one might like :-(.  Reading the `--help` output might be informative as well.  If the script is indeed doing something strange, you will have to edit it.

Comment: @TomTromey Thank you so much. I've found the cause. Sometimes automake is really not easy to use especially in cases where different behaviours occur :(

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on the configure script, I found this piece of code:

`` 448 if test x$GCC = xyes ; then
449     multi_os_directory=`$CC -print-multi-os-directory`
450     case $multi_os_directory in
451       .) ;; # Avoid trailing /.
452       *) libdir=$libdir/$multi_os_directory;;
453     esac
454 fi ``

And this is surely the cause of this problem. `clang -print-multi-os-directory` prints `x86_64` and `gcc` prints '.' with the same option.